# yii2 register js code in a view

Tags: yii2

What is the best way to register js code in yii2 view?

#### 1

```
<?php
    $this->registerJs(
    '$("document").ready(function(){ alert("hi"); });'
    );
  ?>
```

#### 2

```
<?php 
     $this->registerJs('alert("hi");', View::POS_READY);
?>
```

#### 3

```
<?php 
  $script = "function test() { alert('hi');}";    
  $this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END, 'my-options'); 
?>
```

Comment: in my opinion i will use above two.

Comment: I prefer way 2. Simple and safe.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yii2, write code in views

```
<h2>Content</h2>
<?php
$script = <<< JS
    alert("Hi");
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php 
$this->registerJs( <<< EOT_JS_CODE

  // JS code here

EOT_JS_CODE
);
?>
```

So you have not to escape js code

> https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-client-scripts

Answer (score 2):

I prefer use richardfan's widget:

```
use richardfan\widget\JSRegister;

 <?php JSRegister::begin(['position' => static::POS_BEGIN]); ?>
        <script>
           alert('Hello world');
        </script>
<?php JSRegister::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a trivial widget that allows me to keep the code clean and allow proper parsing by the IDE.

**common/widget/InlineScript.php**

```
<?php namespace common\widgets;

/**
 * Easily add JS to the end of the document.
 */
class InlineScript {

    /**
     * Open output buffer.
     */
    public static function listen() {
        ob_start();
    }

    /**
     * Capture the output buffer and register the JS.
     *
     * @param   yii\web\View    $view   The view that should register the JS.
     */
    public static function capture($view) {
        $view->registerJs(preg_replace('~^\s*<script.*>|</script>\s*$~ U', '', ob_get_clean()));
    }

}
```

**usage example (within view)**

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
    <script>
        alert('asd');
    </script>
<?php $this->registerJs(preg_replace('~^\s*<script.*>|</script>\s*$~ U', '', ob_get_clean())) ?>
```

As you see, this does use output buffers, so one needs to be carefull about using this. If every `listen()` isn't followed by exaclty one `capture()` you might get into debugging nightmare :)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do this
Way 1:

```
$script = "
                                $('.summary').append('<div class=\'pull-right\'><button class=\'btn btn-xs\' style=\'background:#ffb3b3;border-color:#ffb3b3;pointer-events:none;height:15px;width:15px\'></button> No BOM Available</div>');
                                ";
                        $this->registerJs($script);
```

Way 2:

```
 $js = <<< 'SCRIPT'
    $(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){
        $('.select-on-check-all').change(function () {
            if ($('.select-on-check-all').is(":checked")) {
                $('#myTable tr').find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
                    keysArr.push($(this).val());
                });
            } else {
                $('#myTable tr').find("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").each(function () {
                    var index = keysArr.indexOf($(this).val());
                    if (index != -1) {
                        keysArr.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
            }

            sessionStorage.setItem("keysArr", keysArr);
        });
    });
SCRIPT;
        $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Remove the quote from the tag 'SCRIPT'