# How to override delete button confirm box in kartik-v/yii2-grid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, yii2

I need to add additinal data to confirm modal.

Of course I can fully override button functionality like

```
[
    'class'    => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'buttons'  => [
            'delete'    => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                return WHAT I NEED
            } ...
```

And then make my own confirm modal with all logic that i need.

But it will be great if I can use built-in confirmation modal, but do some magick with text into the confirm box.

Only one way i see - use some trigger when modal generated done. But cannot choose right trigger (or event).

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**The column of action could be overridden like as below:**

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{view} {update} {delete}',
    'buttons' => [
        'view' => function ($url,$model) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', null, ['title' => 'Exibir', 'onclick' => 'open_teste('.$model->id.')']);
        },
        'update' => function ($url,$model) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['update','id' => $model->id], ['title' => 'Alterar']);
        },
        'delete' => function ($url,$model) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['/module/controller/delete','id' => $model->id], ['title' => 'Excluir', 'data-method' => 'post','data-confirm' => "Deseja realmente excluir este item?"]);
        },
    ],
],
```

So you can define a new route or you can define a new attribute of the button like as **onclick** that could open a modal.

If you'd rather you can also create a new column and create your own buttons like so:

```
[
    'content' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', null, ['onClick' => 'open_teste('.$model->id.')', 'role' => 'button', 'title' => 'Exibir'])
                . Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', ['/main/pts-acao/update-acao-pts', 'id' => $model->id])
                . Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', ['/main/pts-acao/delete-acao-pts', 'id' => $model->id], ['data-method'=> 'post', 'data-confirm' => 'Deseja realmente excluir este item?']);
    },
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'hAlign' => 'center',
],
```

When you create the function in javascript you will need to ensure that the function will be injected at POS_BEGIN like as following

```
<?php
    $js = "function open_teste(id) { alert(id); }";
    $this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_BEGIN);
?>
```

[yii2 register js code in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639326/yii2-register-js-code-in-a-view)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new "buttons" AND "template" attribute in the actionColumn,

```
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
'template' => '{view} {delete}',
'buttons' => [
                'view' => function($url, $data){

                },
                'delete' => function($url, $data){

                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
'buttons'  => [
    'delete'    => function ($url, $model, $key) {
        return Html::a('Statement', $url, ['onClick' => 'return confirm("Your confirmation message?")']
    }
]
```